# In Assassin creed how do we know we're not in combat already in avoid combat secondary objective?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

Sometimes I finish a memory. No body saw me. Some yellow blip happen but that's it. I never pull out my sword.

I finish the memory but I do not know if my secondary objective is fulfilled or not. After a long time I saw that it's not.

How can we always check whether we have already been in combat or not or whether our secondary objective is fulfilled or not earlier?

For example, Memory 01: Black Bart's Gambit

I think I am not seen but that avoid combat objective is never fulfilled. What count as combat anyway? Sometimes soldiers see me, turn red, and I hide, and kill the guy silently. That still doesn't count as combat.

Comment: Just because YOU choose not to fight by running from them does not you aren't "in combat". If the ENEMY is trying to find and kill you, that will most likely count as a combat scenario.

Comment: What @Katustrawfic says is correct. If the notoriety icon turns red it means you have entered combat and that objective will be failed. A yellow notoriety icon does not count as combat. Pausing the game usually lets you check the secondary objectives and will usually inform you if you have already failed an objective (this isn't always the case though, some objectives are not updated until the end or a certain 'checkpoint' in a mission).

Answer (score 2):

The secondary objective appears on screen for a short amount of time at the start of a mission, once it has faded you can review these in the 'Options' menu.

I found that if I failed a secondary objective, rather than appear but crossed out, it just disappeared altogether from any view (not the best UI design in my opinion).

My 'best practise' was to check the secondary objectives at the start of the mission, and check them fairly regularly throughout the playthrough of the mission to check that you haven't inadvertently failed the objective (as it's not always particularly obvious).

Having said that what @ReCaptcha has mentioned in his answer is correct - "Avoid combat" is the same as "Don't be detected" when within a 'restricted area' (those that appear as red on the mini-map), since the enemy immediately go into combat once they detect you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the thing: "Avoid combat" is the same as "Do not be detected". Stealth assassinations are considered as not being detected, as long as you are not spotted. Keep your eye on the screen for those yellow and red indicators which indicate the location a guard is who detects you.